# Get post likes without read_stream permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- User logs in on my website using a custom Facebook Login
- User creates a post on his wall using the feed dialog from my website
- I store the post_id in a database
- I need to query the post in order to get the number of likes it got with FB API

The problem is that Facebook new application review won't authorize my application to use the read_stream permission since it's in a website (as their policy says)

It seems (as on documentation) that I can retrieve a single post (published as "public") with just a valid user access token; but the Open Graph Explorer tool responds with this:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can query a single public post with just a valid access token and without read_stream permission?
Or is there a way I can use the read_stream permission on a website?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you need the amount of likes?

Comment: I need it to build a chart of the most liked post shared (using the feed dialog) from my website

Comment: Without `read_stream` this won't work, and your app won't pass the review for this permission if it isn't an app for a platform on which FB doesn't have a native client.